# More groovifed way of sublist with varying range

Tags: groovy

Student list of 50 students and a teacher list of 3 teachers.

Section XML as the output where each teacher is assigned to a section, and up to 20 students are assigned in that section.

Need to loop on each teacher element, and for each teacher element, loop on the student name from 1-20, than for 2nd teacher, students 21-40 etc.

The following is working code. However, feeling that there could be better groovified way to get `20 students` for a `teacher`

```groovy
def students = """<Students>
    <name> st name 1</name>
    <name> st name 2</name>
    <name> st name 3</name>
    <name> st name 4</name>
    <name> st name 5</name>
    <name> st name 6</name>
    <name> st name 7</name>
    <name> st name 8</name>
    <name> st name 9</name>
    <name> st name 10</name>
    <name> st name 11</name>
    <name> st name 12</name>
    <name> st name 13</name>
    <name> st name 14</name>
    <name> st name 15</name>
    <name> st name 16</name>
    <name> st name 17</name>
    <name> st name 18</name>
    <name> st name 19</name>
    <name> st name 20</name>
    <name> st name 21</name>
    <name> st name 22</name>
    <name> st name 23</name>
    <name> st name 24</name>
    <name> st name 25</name>
    <name> st name 26</name>
    <name> st name 27</name>
    <name> st name 28</name>
    <name> st name 29</name>
    <name> st name 30</name>
    <name> st name 31</name>
    <name> st name 32</name>
    <name> st name 33</name>
    <name> st name 34</name>
    <name> st name 35</name>
    <name> st name 36</name>
    <name> st name 37</name>
    <name> st name 38</name>
    <name> st name 39</name>
    <name> st name 40</name>
    <name> st name 41</name>
    <name> st name 42</name>
    <name> st name 43</name>
    <name> st name 44</name>
    <name> st name 45</name>
    <name> st name 46</name>
    <name> st name 47</name>
    <name> st name 48</name>
    <name> st name 49</name>
    <name> st name 50</name>
</Students>"""

def teachers = """<Teachers>
    <name> Teacher name 1</name>
    <name> Teacher name 2</name>
    <name> Teacher name 3</name>
</Teachers>"""


def getData  = { xml, elementName ->
    def parseXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
    parseXml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == elementName }
}

def teacherNodes = getData( teachers, 'name')
def studentNodes = getData( students, 'name')

def sublist (data, start, end) {
    start == 0 ? data.take(end) : data.drop(start).take(end-start)
}

def incrementBy = 20
def startStudents = 0
def endStundents = incrementBy 
def builder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
builder.encoding = 'UTF-8'
def xml = builder.bind {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration() 
    Assignments {
        teacherNodes.eachWithIndex { teacherNode, index ->          
            Section {
                id (index+1)
                teacher (teacherNode.text())
                studentList {
                    sublist(studentNodes, startStudents, endStundents).each { studentNode ->
                        name (studentNode.text())
                    }
                }               
            }
            startStudents = endStundents
            endStundents += incrementBy
        }       
    }
}

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the code already. If you want to get rid of the increments you could

- use `studentNodes.collate(20)` to create chunks of length `20`
- zip teachers and students together. In Groovy the zip function equivalent is `[list1, list2].transpose()`.

```
def groups = [teacherNodes*.text(), studentNodes*.text().collate(20)].transpose().collectEntries()

def builder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
builder.encoding = 'UTF-8'
def xml = builder.bind {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
    Assignments {
        groups.eachWithIndex { teacherName, studentNames, index ->
            Section {
                id (index+1)
                teacher teacherName
                studentList {
                    studentNames.each { name it }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```